# Bi-Lipschitz embeddings of compact doubling spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces, metric-embeddings

Suppose that $(X,\rho)$ is a compact [doubling metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_space).  Does there necessarily exist an $\epsilon>0$ and a maximal $\epsilon$-net $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n\subseteq X$ such that the map
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Phi:(X,\rho) & \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^n,|\cdot|_2) \\
x&\mapsto \big(\rho(x,x_i)\big)_{i=1}^n
\end{aligned}
$$
is bi-Lipschitz?  (A trivial upper-Lipschitz bound of $\sqrt{n}$ is clear but the lower-Lipschitz bound is far from obvious for me).

---

My question is rooted in the following observations.

**Motivation/Intuition:**
The motivation for my question is rooted in the following two observations.

1. The Assouad embedding theorem, see e.g. [this paper for a recent formulation](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Enaor/homepage%20files/assouad-N(K).pdf), shows that every doubling metric space admits a bi-Hölder embedding into a Euclidean space.  Moreover, it is known that bi-Hölder is necessary, due to the *global* non-embeddability of the Heisenberg group, since the distortion of any closed ball diverges as the radius grows; [this paper](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Enaor/homepage%20files/UCHeis9.pdf).
2. As remarked in this [old MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417185/finite-approximations-to-the-kuratowski-fr%C3%A9chet-embedding), in [this paper of Katz and Katz](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10711-010-9497-4) (with un unpublished quantitative version [found here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.1529.pdf)) shows we know that there is a bi-Lipschitz embedding of any closed and connected Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ into some Euclidean space $(\mathbb{R}^n,|\cdot|_2)$ given by
   $$
   \varphi:\,M\ni x\mapsto \big(\rho_g(x,x_i)\big)_{i=1}^n \in \mathbb{R}^n
   $$
   where $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is any maximal $\epsilon$-net for some sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$ and $\rho_g$ is the geodesic distance on $(M,g)$.
   Clearly, compactness is needed here, since it is well-known that the hyperbolic plane cannot be bi-Lipschitz embedded into any Euclidean space.
3. I comment that smoothness is not needed in (1) since the existence of $\Phi$ is obvious for any finite metric space.

---

**Update:**

**Claim:** Suppose that there exists some $0<\epsilon\le 1$ and a finite set $Y\subseteq X$ (depending on $\epsilon>0$) with the property that for every $x,z\in X$ there is some (possibly not unique) $y_{x,z}\in Y$ satisfying
$$
\epsilon \rho(x,z)\le |\rho(x,y_{x,z})-\rho(z,y_{x,z})|.
$$
Then, the map $\Phi(x)\mapsto (\rho(x,y))_{y\in Y}$ is a bi-Lipschitz embedding into the $|Y|$-dimensional Euclidean space.

*Proof:*

If this case, the finiteness of $Y$ implies that
$$
\epsilon \rho(x,z)\le |\rho(x,y_{x,z})-\rho(z,y_{x,z})|
\le \max_{y\in Y}\, |\rho(x,y)-\rho(z,y)|
\le \|\Phi(x)-\Phi(y)\|_2
\le |Y|^{1/2}\,\max_{y\in Y}\, |\rho(x,y)-\rho(z,y)| \le |Y|^{1/2}\rho(x,y)
$$
where I used the fact that $|Y|<\infty$ and $x\mapsto \rho(x,y)$ is $1$-Lipschitz for every $y\in Y$.

---

**Updated Question:**
So doesn't every $\epsilon$-packing do the trick and shouldn't any packing exist since packing numbers are upper-bounded by covering numbers, and in a doubling space all covering numbers are $O((\operatorname{diam}(X,\rho)\epsilon)^{-d})$ where $d$ is the doubling dimension of $(X,\rho)$ and $\operatorname{diam}(X,\rho)$ is its diameter?

In which case, why not take $\epsilon=1$?  *(Besides the fact that the distortion may be sub-optimal).*

---

**Thoughts:** I guess the main challenge is to control the distortion and to show that one can get it to converge to $1$ as $\epsilon\downarrow 0$ (and this $n\uparrow \infty$ in general).

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand something, but wouldn't a tree be a counterexample: with edge lengths for example like this . 1/2 -> {. 1/4 -> {...}, . 1/4 -> {...}} (sorry for the notation, hope it is clear)

Comment: @LorenoHeer Is such an infinite (discrete I guess) tree doubling?  Since for the finite things go through ofc.

Comment: @LorenoHeer Moreover, this tree is not complete so it is not compact.  Unless I'm overlooking something.

Comment: I meant metric tree (not discrete) with edge lengths as indicated 1/2 then branching and subsequently smaller. The limit points could be added to make the space complete I think, unless I overlook something. It is doubling with doubling constant 4, as far as I can tell. But double check this :)

Comment: Aha, interesting, so one really needs distances to sets; as in some proofs.

Comment: @LorenoHeer Whats your intuition about what's fundamentally different here, between the tree and the closed Riemannian manifolds?

Comment: good question. I think I am missing something somewhere or my example somehow is erroneous. I will think about it some more later when I have time.

Comment: while I guess my example could be viewed as a smooth manifold, there would be no way to extend a riemannian metric to the boundary (it would be degenerate there).

Comment: @LorenoHeer So I guess one only needs this: there is some $0<\epsilon\le 1$ and a finite subset $Y\subseteq X$ such that: for every $x,z\in X$ there is some (possibly not unique) $y_{x,z}\in Y$ satisfying $(1-\epsilon)\rho(x,z)\le |\rho(x,y_{x,z})-\rho(z,y_{x,z})|$.  But shouldn't any $(1-\epsilon)/2$-packing do the trick?  And shouldn't a packing exist since packing numbers are upper-bounded by doubling numbers and these are controlled in doubling metric spaces by the doubling constant + the doubling dimension?

*(I updated my question accordingly.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There are many compact, doubling metric spaces with no bi-Lipschitz embedding in a Hilbert space. Some examples:

- The closed unit ball in the (continuous) Heisenberg group with its Carnot-Carath'eodory metric. (See, e.g., Theorem 6.1 of "Differentiability of Lipschitz maps from metric spaces to Banach spaces" and observe that the differentiability argument is purely local.)
- The example in Theorem 2.3 of "Bilipschitz embeddings of metric spaces into space forms" by Lang and Plaut.
- The examples constructed by Laakso in "Ahlfors $Q$-regular spaces with arbitrary $Q>1$ admitting weak Poincar'e inequality" and (suitably compactified) "Plane with $A_\infty$-weighted metric not bilipschitz embeddable to $\mathbb{R}^n$". See Proposition 1.23 of "Doubling conformal densities" by Bonk, Heinonen, and Rohde.

Comment: Ah so even for compact spaces one does need a holder type exponent...interesting...

Comment: So with the holder exponent, does it sufficie to consider the distance to finitwly many points